# start_session() from RWebdriver package doesn't work

Tags: r

1. I've installed package from git_hub under RStudio by:

   ```
   install_github(repo = "Rwebdriver",username = "crubba")
   ```
2. Downloaded and started Selenium server  v.3.3.1 from the command prompt by:

   ```
   >java -jar seleniumXXX.jar
   ```
3. When I'm trying to run this command under RStudio:

   ```
   start_session(root = "http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/", browser ="firefox")
   ```

   I'm getting an error:

   ```
   Error in serverDetails$value[[1]] : subscript out of bounds
   ```

I haven't any idea what is it.
Is anybody help me?

RStudio Version 0.99.903
R version 3.3.3
RWebdriver Version 0.1
OS - Windows 10
selenium server version 3.3.1
Java Version 8 update 121 (build 1.8.0_121-b13)

Comment: That is an incredibly old repo. Why not use https://github.com/ropensci/RSelenium?

Comment: Yes, I just found this package, install it(install.package("RSelenium"), downloaded chrome driver .exe, set up system path to this driver, started this driver(It's listening port 9515) . After this commands: 
`remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost" , port = 9515 , browserName = "chrome")`
`remDr$open()`
  I've got an error:
`Error in resContent[["status"]] : subscript out of bounds`
What's a problem?

Comment: When I am trying firefox driver I am getting:
`Connection refused` error.

Comment: Unless you really need to use Firefox & Selenium, give `splashr` a try: https://github.com/hrbrmstr/splashr

Comment: `http://localhost:/wd/hub/static/resource/hub.html` in my browser also raises `Connection refused`